# How to make a generic Array.sumPair which mimic Array.sum?

Tags: f#, inline

I would like to sum up an `('a* 'b)` array

```
let inline sumPair (array: ('a * 'b)[]) =
    let array1, array2 = array |> Array.unzip
    (Array.sum array1, array2 |> Array.sum)
```

Clearly this is not ideal. I think maybe one way is to define `+` and `zero` of my `tuple`, and use the built in `Array.sum`, but couldn't find any related tutorial. Any help?

Comment: Why is this not ideal? Why is defining `+` and `zero` for `tuple` better?

Comment: @Daniel suppose I am writing a personal library, and hope it to be as efficient as possible. I don't know if `+` ... is better.

Comment: Why not using something simple and readable like `Array.fold(fun (a0, b0) (a, b) -> a0+a, b0+b) (GenericZero, GenericZero)` ?

Comment: @bytebuster thank u, `GenericZero` is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way. This doesn't require you to use GenericZero:

```
let inline sumPair (array : (^T * ^U)[]) =
    array
    |> Array.reduce (fun (x0, y0) (x1, y1) ->
        (x0 + x1), (y0 + y1))
```

EDIT : Or, if you want maximum compatibility with `Array.sum` (as Daniel suggested), just add a check for an empty array:

```
let inline sumPair (array : (^T * ^U)[]) =
    if Array.isEmpty array then
        LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero, LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    else
        array
        |> Array.reduce (fun (x0, y0) (x1, y1) ->
            (x0 + x1), (y0 + y1))
```

This code won't be entirely inlined (the IL will still have a call to Array.reduce), but it does have the benefit of being parallelizable if you have a huge array.

Comment: Is there any specific reason use `^T` instead of `'a`? Is `reduce` better than `fold`?

Comment: This doesn't behave the same as `Array.sum`. It doesn't handle an empty array.

Comment: @colinfang `^T` is a statically-resolved generic parameter, which can only be used with an inlined function. It allows you to add certain constraints to the generic parameter, like requiring that `^T` and `^U` support the `+` operator. `reduce` is better than `fold` for *this* problem, because that's exactly what a sum is -- a reduction which uses the `+` operation.

Comment: It seems even if I use `'T` then as long as i type in inline, the compiler would auto treat it as `^T`

Answer (score 4):

```
let inline sumPair source = 
  let inline zero() = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
  Seq.fold (fun (xAcc, yAcc) (x, y) -> (xAcc + x, yAcc + y)) (zero(), zero()) source
```

As you stated in your comment that it should be as efficient as possible, I don't think anything can beat the imperative version:

```
let inline sumPair source = 
  let mutable xAcc = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
  let mutable yAcc = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
  for x, y in source do
    xAcc <- xAcc + x
    yAcc <- yAcc + y
  (xAcc, yAcc)
```

It should require fewer allocations than the first one.

Comment: why do u define a function for `GenericZero`? 1. Can i use value bind such as `let zero = GenericZero`? 2. Can I just use `GenericZero` without introduce `zero()`

Comment: Using a value instead of a function will constrain the pairs to be the same type since it's being used as the seed value for both. As is, it's a generic function, returning zero for any supported type.

Answer (score 1):

If you worry about creating temporary arrays, here is a concise version using sequence:

```
let inline sumPair (array: _ []) =
    Seq.sumBy fst array, Seq.sumBy snd array
```

A slightly longer variant, but probably more efficient one is:

```
let inline sumPair (array: _ []) =
        array |> Seq.map fst |> Seq.sum, array |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.sum
```